# Putting cells in Seurat dimplot selectively

Tags: r, seurat

I am going to adjust Seurat dimplot in a way avoiding some cells so both my dimplot and heatmap look nice

If you please consider this picture, you would see some cells are far from the clusters so I want to avoid them in dimplot and of course for heatmap (coming from finding markers).

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Can you suggest me a piece of code doing that?
Thanks

Comment: Answered on GitHub here: https://github.com/satijalab/seurat/issues/2338

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a GUI you could select the cells interactively:

```
plot <- DimPlot(seurat_obj, reduction = "umap")
```

Then select the cells by clicking around them

```
select.cells <- CellSelector(plot = plot)
Idents(seurat_obj, cells = select.cells) <- "SubCells"
```

and subset based on these cells

```
sub_cells <- WhichCells(seurat_obj, idents = "SubCells")
sub_obj <- subset(seurat_obj, cells = sub_cells)
```

You could then use subobject in your downstream dimplot.

See [here](https://satijalab.org/seurat/v3.0/visualization_vignette.html) for some of the interactive options. I guess you could outright subset on UMAP coordinates, but that may not always be easy if your boundary isn't linear.